# Hide line but keep marker when using plotyy

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm plotting some data in matlab using

```
[hAxes,hBar,hLine] = plotyy(0:n , data , 0:n , moredata , 'bar' , 'plot');
```

And to get circular markers I call

```
set(hLine,'Marker','o');
```

Giving the picture

[image: Plot of data]

But I want to remove the blue lines between the markers and just show the circular markers. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply set linestyle to `'none'`

```
set( hLine, 'LineStyle', 'none' );
```